# How to access azure key vault secrets from web application hosted on local machine IIS and debugged by attaching IIS worker process?

Tags: azure-keyvault

The objective is to read all the secret values from from .net framework 4.6 web application hosted on local IIS? The application is bit legacy and it can only be debugged by attaching to worker process.
I am trying to access azure key vault secrets by using the below code, so that storage of keys can be avoided in the application configuration files.

```
var keyVaultPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultStorage"];
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secrets = keyVaultClient.GetSecretsAsync(keyVaultPath).Result;
_secretValues = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var item in secrets)
{
      var secret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{keyVaultPath}/secrets/{item.Identifier.Name}").Result;
      _secretValues.TryAdd(item.Identifier.Name, secret.Value);
}
```

Before running this code, ensured to login to azure subscription using the below commands

```
az login 
az account set --subscription
```

The same code runs well in .Net core application as well as in .Net framework 4.6 web application hosted on IIS Express. It does not run when hosted on local machine IIS.

Error thrown running the code from IIS worker process.

```
AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/. Exception Message: Tried the following 4 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) endpoint. Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI setup.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: vault.azure.net, Authority: login.windows.net/. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-17ev678d\azure-cli\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-17ev678d\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 509, in get_default_cli
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-17ev678d\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 51, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\knack\util.py", line 38, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(d)
  File "os.py", line 220, in makedirs
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\.azure'

Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: vault.azure.net, Authority: login.windows.net/. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Active Directory Integrated Authentication. Access token could not be acquired. unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
```

Comment: Error thats thrown running the code:

Comment: You need to run the process as yourself then grant you access to key vault if your running on windows machine and windows account sync to aad...

Comment: set app pool identity to run under my user context. keyvault resource has been given access to the logged in user. I don't understand windows account sync to aad